# Will inverting amplifier's input impedance change if its output is saturated?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, ltspice

I found that when my inverting amplifier's output saturates, its input impedance becomes larger.
This is my schematic. As you can see on the left, when the inverting amplifier's gain is 10, with an input 1 volt 1kHz sine wave, the op-amp's output(not out1) will saturates(3.3V power supply), which I think will enlarge the inverting amplifier's input impedance, which is 10k(R1) if not saturates. I think so because the high pass filter created by C1 and Rin of inverting amplifier's cutoff frequency is not the same(lower) as C2 and R3, which on the right, without output saturates. You can see this for Vout1 and Vout2.

So am I right?

[image]

Comment: You have a highpass filter in there, of course the output will change with different cutoff frequencies... on top of a closed loop, so the gain and a bunch of others, output impedance, PSRR, etc, will change with it. What you are talking about, though, is not output impedance.

Answer (score 1):

> I found that when my inverting amplifier's output saturates, its input impedance becomes larger

Sure, that's reasonable.

Once the output is saturated, the op-amp can no longer maintain the virtual ground at the inverting input. Since that node is no longer "artificially" made a low impedance node, the input impedance of the circuit will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a DC amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foXZy7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Inverting amplifier with gain of -1. (a) Not in saturation. (b) In saturation.*

- In (a) the input impedance will be seen as 10 kΩ to ground for all in-range voltages.
- In (b) the amplifier has been driven into saturation and is unable to hold the inverting input at virtual ground. With 30 V in the inverting input will rise to +10 V. While the input resistance, R3 is still 10 k the load seen by the input signal will be reduced by 33% because of the 33% reduction in potential difference across R3.

The effective input impedance in this case will vary from constant 10 kΩ when not in saturation to a lower value when in saturation. If the clipping is symmetrical the change in impedance will be too.

Your circuit is AC coupled but the same effect will be seen by the source.

Comment: Could you please explain how did you get 33% reduction?

Comment: OK. (1) What's the input impedance of Figure 1 A? (Checking to see if you understand virtual earth / ground.)

Comment: That's 10k, I haven't learnt impedance on saturated op amp.

Comment: Correct. (2) Do you understand that the inverting amplifier is set with a gain of -1? (3) What will happen when the input voltage is +30 V?

Comment: Yes I understand, the output will be saturated to -10V. As to how the input impedance drop is where I haven't understand.

Comment: The op amp model for non-saturated op amp is like [this](https://www.tina.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Op-ampcircuit2-10.png), which I got from [this](https://www.tina.com/resources/home/ideal-operational-amplifiers-2/4-input-resistance-of-op-amp-circuits/). I could calculate it easily. But how about the model of the saturated one?

Comment: OK. (4) If the output is clamped at -10 V and the IN- is driven to +10 V then the ground point is (kind-of) half way along R4. That means that the input impedance = R3 + R4/2 = 10k + 5k = 15k. Now the input impedance has increased from 10k to 15k (a factor of 1.5) the load is scaled by \$ \frac 1 {1.5} = 0.666 \$ and hence the load has reduced by 33%. (Higher resistance = lower load.)

Comment: I've never bothered with those op-amp models so I won't try to help you with them.

Comment: It's okay, thanks that you've been helped me so much. I've confirmed it by running a DC sweep analysis on LTspice, as Vin approaches infinity, Rin will be equal to 20k. Thus Rin = R3 + x*R4. Picking 1/2 as your example is one way to get the exact Rin as it is intuitively correct. Now, what is the x as a function of Vin and Vout is where I haven't found the solution yet. I just love leaning lol.